Error : Network request failed between Expo (React Native) and Express (but worked in Postman)
I had a project with a backend in Express and a frontend who is running with Expo and I wanted to connect my backend and my frontend. But I have this error : Network request failed.
I read many forums and I already switch my localhost address for my ipV4 : "http://172.11.60.128:3333".
On Postman and on another project (in React) the call worked but not on my Expo Project ‍♀️.
Postman request
There are my files :
export function GET() {
    console.log("first")
    fetch("http://172.11.60.128:3333/")
        .then((res) => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error("Connexion non établie")
            }
            console.log("no response OK")
        })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("Connexion au backend réussie !")
        })
        .catch((error) =>
            console.error("Une erreur s'est produite :", error.message)
        )
}

connect+api.ts in app directory
import React, { useEffect } from "react"
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native" // Importe useNavigation depuis react-navigation/native
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar"
import { StyleSheet, Text, ScrollView, View, Button } from "react-native"

export const ChitChatsScreen = () => {
    const backendUrl = process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL
    const navigation = useNavigation() // Utilise useNavigation pour obtenir l'objet de navigation

    // const fetchDatas = () => {
    //  fetch("http://172.21.62.178:3333/")
    //      .then((res) => {
    //          if (!res.ok) {
    //              throw new Error("Connexion non établie")
    //          }
    //          console.log("no response OK")
    //      })
    //      .then((data) => {
    //          console.log("Connexion au backend réussie !")
    //      })
    //      .catch((error) =>
    //          console.error("Une erreur s'est produite :", error.message)
    //      )
    // }

    const fetchDatas = () => {
        console.log("je vais fetch")
        fetch("/connect")
            .then((res) => {
                console.log("réponse reçue du front : ", res)
            })
            .catch((error) =>
                console.error(
                    "Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'appel :",
                    error.message
                )
            )
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("Le composant ChitChatsScreen est monté")
        fetchDatas()
    }, [navigation])

    return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>Tous les chats</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
        </ScrollView>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#ffe5d9",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        paddingHorizontal: 40,
    },
    title: {
        fontSize: 32,
        fontWeight: "700",
        backgroundColor: "#ffff",
        padding: 20,
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
})


MyScreen.ts in screens directory
{
    "expo": {
        "name": "test",
        "slug": "test",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "orientation": "portrait",
        "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
        "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
        "splash": {
            "image": "./assets/splash.png",
            "resizeMode": "contain",
            "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
        },
        "experiments": { "tsconfigPaths": false },
        "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
        "ios": {
            "supportsTablet": true
        },
        "android": {
            "adaptiveIcon": {
                "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
                "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
            },
            "permissions": ["INTERNET"]
        },
        "web": {
            "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
            "bundler": "metro",
            "output": "server"
        },
        "extra": {
            "proxy": "http://172.21.62.178:3333"
        }
    }
}


app.json in my frontend project
const express = require("express")
const cors = require("cors")
const app = express()
const port = 3333

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`| Listening on port | ${port} |`)
})

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json()) 

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content, Accept, Content-Type, Authorization"
    )
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
        "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS"
    )
    next()
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("Connected to Backend ")
})


index.js in my backend project
Do you have any suggestion for this ? Thanks  !
I want to see logs succed for connection to my Express backend when I go to my screen who called the backend.
